# Why my variables are undefined i click on the submit button?

Tags: cakephp

I have fields in a form with variables from the Controller TownsController, I use "set" to be able to affchés in sight. I arrive at the desired result, the problem is that when I want to send my information by clicking on the submit button, I have several errors telling me that the variable is undefined.

Before i click on the submit button :

[image]

After i click on the submit button :

[image]

The view :

```
        <h2>Informations de votre ville</h2>

          <?php echo $this->Form->create('Town'); ?>

              <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xs-6">
              <?php echo $this->Form->input('statut',array(
              'label' => 'Statut',
              'type' => 'select',
              'options' => array(
                'Village'=>'Village',
                'Ville'=>'Ville'),
              'selected' => $selectedstatut,
              'class' => 'form-control',
              'id' => 'town_statut_municipal',  
              'empty' => __('Statut municipal')
              ));
              ?>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                     <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('type' => 'text', 'id' => 'town_name', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Choisir un statut municipal', 'label' => 'Nom')); ?>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('country', array('type' => 'select', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'Pays', 'id' => 'town_country', 'onchange' => "print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);", 'selected' => $selectedcountry, 'empty' => false,
                      'options' => array(
                        'Canada'=>'Canada',
                        'USA'=>'USA'))); ?>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
              <?php 
              echo $this->Form->input('localisation', array('type' => 'select', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'Localisation', 'id' => 'state', 'empty' => $namelocalisation,
                    'options' => $localisations)); ?>
                  </div>
              </div>  

              <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <br>
                        <?php
                            $options = array('label' => 'Sauvegarder', 'class' => 'btn', 'div' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-success');
                            echo $this->Form->end($options);
                          ?>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </form>
```

TownsController (edit view) :

```
    public function edit(){
    $town_id = $this->Auth->user('town_id');
    $user_id = $this->Auth->user('user_id');
    if(!$town_id && !$user_id) {
        $this->redirect('/');
        die();
    }
    $this->Town->id = $town_id;
    if($this->request->is('put') || $this->request->is('post')) {
    }
    else {
         $this->request->data = $this->Town->read(array('name', 'country', 'localisation', 'statut'), null);
         $selectedstatut = $this->Session->read('Auth.Town.statut');
         $this->set(compact('selectedstatut'));
         $selectedcountry = $this->Session->read('Auth.Town.country');
         $this->set(compact('selectedcountry'));
         $countryuser = $this->Session->read('Auth.Town.country');

         if($countryuser = 'Canada') {
         $namelocalisation = 'Province';
         $localisations = array(
                'Alberta'=>"Alberta",
                'British Columbia'=>"British Columbia", 
                'Manitoba'=>"Manitoba", 
                'New Brunswick'=>"New Brunswick", 
                'Newfoundland'=>"Newfoundland", 
                'Northwest Territories'=>"Northwest Territories", 
                'Nova Scotia'=>"Nova Scotia", 
                'Nunavut'=>"Nunavut", 
                'Ontario'=>"Ontario", 
                'Prince Edward Island'=>"Prince Edward Island", 
                'Quebec'=>"Quebec", 
                'Saskatchewan'=>"Saskatchewan", 
                'Yukon Territory'=>"Yukon Territory");
         }
         if($countryuser = 'USA') {
         $namelocalisation = 'État';
         $localisations = array(
                'Alabama'=>"Alabama",
                'Alaska'=>"Alaska", 
                'Arizona'=>"Arizona", 
                'Arkansas'=>"Arkansas", 
                'California'=>"California", 
                'Colorado'=>"Colorado", 
                'Connecticut'=>"Connecticut", 
                'Delaware'=>"Delaware", 
                'District Of Columbia'=>"District Of Columbia", 
                'Florida'=>"Florida", 
                'Georgia'=>"Georgia", 
                'Hawaii'=>"Hawaii", 
                'Idaho'=>"Idaho", 
                'Illinois'=>"Illinois", 
                'Indiana'=>"Indiana", 
                'Iowa'=>"Iowa", 
                'Kansas'=>"Kansas", 
                'Kentucky'=>"Kentucky", 
                'Louisiana'=>"Louisiana", 
                'Maine'=>"Maine", 
                'Maryland'=>"Maryland", 
                'Massachusetts'=>"Massachusetts", 
                'Michigan'=>"Michigan", 
                'Minnesota'=>"Minnesota", 
                'Mississippi'=>"Mississippi", 
                'Missouri'=>"Missouri", 
                'Montana'=>"Montana",
                'Nebraska'=>"Nebraska",
                'Nevada'=>"Nevada",
                'New Hampshire'=>"New Hampshire",
                'New Jersey'=>"New Jersey",
                'New Mexico'=>"New Mexico",
                'New York'=>"New York",
                'North Carolina'=>"North Carolina",
                'North Dakota'=>"North Dakota",
                'Ohio'=>"Ohio", 
                'Oklahoma'=>"Oklahoma", 
                'Oregon'=>"Oregon", 
                'Pennsylvania'=>"Pennsylvania", 
                'Rhode Island'=>"Rhode Island", 
                'South Carolina'=>"South Carolina", 
                'South Dakota'=>"South Dakota",
                'Tennessee'=>"Tennessee", 
                'Texas'=>"Texas", 
                'Utah'=>"Utah", 
                'Vermont'=>"Vermont", 
                'Virginia'=>"Virginia", 
                'Washington'=>"Washington", 
                'West Virginia'=>"West Virginia", 
                'Wisconsin'=>"Wisconsin", 
                'Wyoming'=>"Wyoming");
         }
         $this->set('localisations', $localisations);
         $this->set('namelocalisation', $namelocalisation);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you set those variables IF the request is not POST. When you click on Submit your code will enter in the "isPost" condition, hence the variables localisations, namelocalisation, selectedcountry and selectedstatut are never set.

Here's what I would do (pseudo code)

```
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
    if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
$selectedstatut = $this->Session->read('Auth.Town.statut');
etc...
```

Notice I am setting the view variables outside the if statement so that if save fails (because validation) then we set the variables again.